# maintain scrollposition in Coolgridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

I have an asp 3.5 site that communicates with an Oacle DB. I put a CoolGridView on it that binds some object and when users click a CheckBox I fill in a textbox on that row with some data.
However, the scrollbar behaves weird, sometimes it jumps to the top sometimes to the bottom whenever I select anything and creates a postback.
Is there an easy way to avoid this? Some hidden property I never noticed?
And yes, I have the maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack set, I read somewhere that I need to have my CoolGridView in an UpdatePanel. Well I don't, never used them, seem that I need to rewrite the whole Grid if I change this?
But maybe I have to?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working, wrapping only the GridView in an updatepanel and throwing in a ScriptManager sem to have solved it..